# Magento2 : checkout_cart_product_add_after Event not working with API

Tags: magento2, cart, event-observer, api

I have created an observer on event `"checkout_cart_product_add_after"` and its working fine for web but not working with REST API.

Comment: when you add product to cart using API, can you see it also in cart from magento storefront ?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior (an event, di happens for one area and not the other) seems to be related to the area. I'm guessing that you have declared the event to the **frontend** area `etc/frontend/events.xml`.

You should add that event the *"global" area* `etc/events.xml`

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this you will have to dispatch the event from your API code itself.

Use `_eventManager`  to dispatch the event and pass relevant parameters.

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'checkout_cart_product_add_after',
            [$this->_eventObject => $this, 'product' => $product]
        );
```